# Sending messages from Servlet -> Servlet and Servlet->JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, httpresponse

I am having  web application where I have to send messages from one servlet to another and servlet to JSP. The default way to do that would be using `RequestDispatcher` and calling `request.setAttribute("name",message);`.

True, but I have some places where I have to use `response.sendRedirect()` in order to stop multiple submitting of forms on manual refersh.

The most known way to send messages in this case would be using `Session` and adding the message to the session.

However using session for passing messages is not a good idea, because the message is actually an item which should be belong to the `request scope`. So, any other good way of passing it to servlet and Jsp? In JSP I am using `JSTL` so please tell me how to get the passed object using that as well.

Comment: Are you using Struts 2?

Comment: @exoddus: No..........

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you could use `cookies`, `Query String`,  `url re-writing`, etc.

Query String:

```
String path = 'next.jsp';
path += '?name=' + messge;
```

You can use:

```
response.sendRedirect(path);
```

OR

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
```

On the landing page you can get the message just by `request.getParameter("name")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any framework like Struts 2 you could store it to `application scope` https://struts.apache.org/docs/accessing-application-session-request-objects.html

If you are using a simply Servlet and `session` is not space free enought to store what you want, you could consider storing it to file disk or DB and then read it from any `Servlet` you want.

This question is related if it's your case: [What is the best place to store a configuration file in a Java web application (WAR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96247/what-is-the-best-place-to-store-a-configuration-file-in-a-java-web-application)