# Where should I put a configuration file needed by one of my maven jar dependency?

Tags: java, maven

So I have 2 projects, let's say Project1 & Project2.

The first one is a Java application (no maven) which is working well, reading a configuration file as follow:

```
public static void init() {
  Path path = Paths.get("config.properties");
  byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
  ...
}
```

I created project1.jar from this project, and I'm using it as a maven dependency in my Project2, which is a Dynamic Web Project.
This dependency is well included because I'm able to use other part of it without any trouble.

The problem I get now is when I try to call the `init()` method from my Project2, I get a `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`.

I guess it's because I have to put that `config.properties` file somewhere in Project2 tree (I don't want it to be included in the project1.jar)

I took this `config.properties` file and tried to put it everywhere in my maven tree `WebContent`, `META-INF`, `WEB-INF`, `target`, each sub-directory of `target`, `src`... Nothing is working, I still get the Exception.

Do I have to include it in the `pom.xml` in some way? If yes, how? If no... Any idea?

Comment: Create a directory structure like `src/main/resources` and dump the config.properties file in the resources folder. See if this works.

Comment: Sadly no, I still get the exception

Comment: I suggest you to take a peek at the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96247/what-is-the-best-place-to-store-a-configuration-file-in-a-java-web-application).
The **Project2** is a servlet, so you have to understand the concept of [context](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servletcontext.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link, so if I'm unable to manually pass the `path` as parameter to `init()`, the method will never find it?

Comment: By the way, how did you add project1 as dependency to project2 ? Also, try these 2 things.  1. In Project1, right-click on the package and select New -> File, then enter the filename including the ".properties" suffix and put your contents in it.  2. Create a `respurces` folder at the same level as `src` in you project1 and place the properties file in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Straight forward.
Do what RITZ XAVI Suggested. add to src/main/resources

Then replace you init function as follows.

```
public static void init() {
    InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    ...
}
```

As per how you added as maven dependency I think you must have installed the jar in your repo with custom group and artifact id